# How does this javascript object have reference to this inline function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

```
var ninja = {
    chirp: function signal(n) {
    return n > 1 ? signal(n - 1) + "-chirp" : "chirp";
    }
};
assert(ninja.chirp(3) == "chirp-chirp-chirp", "Works as we would expect it to!");
var samurai = { chirp: ninja.chirp };
ninja = {};
assert(samurai.chirp(3) == "chirp-chirp-chirp","The method correctly calls itself.");
```

Compare this to

```
var ninja = {
    chirp: function(n) {
    return n > 1 ? signal(n - 1) + "-chirp" : "chirp";
    }
};
assert(ninja.chirp(3) == "chirp-chirp-chirp", "does not work");
var samurai = { chirp: ninja.chirp };
ninja = {};
assert(samurai.chirp(3) == "chirp-chirp-chirp","The method cannot reference function.");
```

How does `samurai` have reference to the `chirp` property in the `ninja` object after the `ninja` object has been redefined to `ninja = {};`?

Comment: A function is an object. A variable (or property) *names* an object (or a primitive value); and an object is always itself, regardless of however many *names* it has (ie. regardless of how many times it has been assigned, the object is .. itself). The term *names* can be substituted for "refers to", which while colloquially equivalent, it *not* to be confused with a 'reference' as that is an implementation detail (and not defined by ECMAScript in this sense). Likewise, there are no 'pointers' or in JavaScript; can describe the behavior with simpler rules..

Comment: ..tldr; assignment of a variable (or property) outside of an object's property-graph (or lexical closures) has *no effect* of the objects that it [may have] previously *named* (or "referred to").

Answer (score 0):

Variables that reference functions or objects are essentially *pointers to memory locations*. When a variable gets reassigned, whatever's at the memory location it used to point to doesn't get changed - it's just that said object will eventually be garbage-collected once nothing *anywhere* in the script can reference it anymore.

So, the `ninja = {}` doesn't change the object that `ninja` originally used to be. Because `samurai` has a reference to `ninja.chirp`, the `ninja.chirp` function will not be garbage collected - or, at least, not yet, not while `samurai` still exists.

The `chirp` or `signal` function can call itself with `signal(n - 1)` because it's a *named function* - it's named `signal`, so it can reference and call itself by using its function name. Anonymous functions have no names and so they can't reference themselves like that.

Comment: if you were to change the inline function in ninja to an anonymous function samurai code not reference the chirp property.

Comment: Indeed, because `signal` is a *named function* - that's how it can recursively call itself, by referencing its name. Anonymous arrow functions have no names and can't recursively call themselves like that.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Functions can exist independently of objects, and vice versa. Think of the `signal` function and the `ninja.chirp` property as 2 separate entities, both in the program memory. `ninja.chirp` is just a pointer to `signal`. When you assign `samurai.chirp` to `ninja.chirp` you are creating another pointer to the `signal` function. Destroying `ninja.chirp` does not destroy `signal`, at least not as long as something else is referencing it, in this case it's `samurai.chirp`. Furthermore, it would also work for an anonymous function as long as the function is not recursive, example below:

```js
var ninja = {
  chirp: function (n) {
    return console.log("chirp "+n+" times!");
  }
};

ninja.chirp(3);
var samurai = { chirp: ninja.chirp };

ninja = {};
samurai.chirp(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `chirp` property of a `ninja` object is referencing a function somewhere in memory (named `signal`.)  The `ninja` object basically holds a 'remote control' to that function.  This 'remote control' is named `chirp`.  When you created the `samurai` object, you created another 'remote control' that referenced the `signal` function.

The function will still exist in memory as long as there are 'remote controls' pointing to it.